# How to reveal text from a button that is clicked, then hide the previous text if new button is cllicked

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make it so that when I click on a category, the text, for that category appears. Then when a new category is clicked, the previous category text is removed, and the text for the new category takes its place. Right now, no matter what  button I click, all items appear.

index.html

```
<div class='container'>
    <button class="button">Fit guide</button>
    <button class="button">Care</button>
    <button class="button">Materials</button>
    
    <div class="single-entry">
        <p class="fit">lkasdnf;aksdjf;askdjflkjsdhflkajsdhflaksjdhfaksjdhflkasjdhfasjdbflaksjdhflkasdjhfkajsdbas</p>

    </div>

    
    <div class="single-entry">
        <p>lkasdnf;aksdjf;askdjflkjsdhflkajsdhflaksjdhfaksjdhflkasjdhfasjdbflaksjdhflkasdjhfkajsdbas</p>

    </div>

    <div class="single-entry">
        <p>lkasdnf;aksdjf;askdjflkjsdhflkajsdhflaksjdhfaksjdhflkasjdhfasjdbflaksjdhflkasdjhfkajsdbas</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

index.js

```
const displayEntryButton = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const test = document.querySelector('.fit');


for (var j = 0; j < displayEntryButton.length; j++) {
    displayEntryButton[j].addEventListener('click', function () {
        const allEntries = document.querySelectorAll('.single-entry');
        for (let index = 0; index < allEntries.length; index++) {
            if(allEntries[index].style.display === 'none') {
                allEntries[index].style.display = 'block'
            } else {
                allEntries[index].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adjusted your code a bit to get things working.

My adjustment primarily adds an **id** to each entry div and a matching **data-value** to each button.

The **id** and **data-value** are then used for comparison when a button is clicked. If there's a match, the corresponding content is displayed.

Try the snippet below. - Comments are included within the code.

```js
const displayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const entryDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.single-entry');

//start for loop to iterate over each button
for (j = 0; j < displayButtons.length; j++) {
  //btnValue is declared to capture the data-value attribute
  const btnValue = displayButtons[j].getAttribute('data-value');
  displayButtons[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
    //nested loop to iterate over each entry div
    for (i = 0; i < entryDivs.length; i++) {
      //entryId is declared to capture the div id
      const entryId = entryDivs[i].id;
      //if btnValue matches entryId
      if (btnValue === entryId) {
        //show the corresponding content
        entryDivs[i].style.display = "block"
      } else {
        //otherwise show nothing
        entryDivs[i].style.display = "none"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/*set all entries to display none by default*/

.single-entry {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

  <!-- Here we are setting a data-value on each button -->
  <!-- The data-value must match the id for each corresponding div -->
  <button class="button" data-value="fit">Fit guide</button>
  <button class="button" data-value="care">Care</button>
  <button class="button" data-value="materials">Materials</button>

  <!-- Each div below has an id to match each buttons data-value -->
  <div class="single-entry" id="fit">
    <p>FIT ENTRY</p>
  </div>

  <div class="single-entry" id="care">
    <p>CARE ENTRY</p>
  </div>

  <div class="single-entry" id="materials">
    <p>MATERIALS ENTRY</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Guess I need more practice. I didn’t think to use the data-value attribute

Comment: No problem, glad to help. - I will say that there are a few other ways to do this but I didn't want to stray too far from the nested loop you were using. Best of luck to you, happy coding!

Comment: I was looking for other ways to do this but I honestly was not able to find something to make it work.